# Spring Boot async task stuck on shutdown

Tags: java, spring-boot, threadpool

As per spring documentation for `setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown`

> Set whether to wait for scheduled tasks to complete on shutdown

Does it mean that if any task is stuck on some long running process and we explicity try to stop the container, it will not be terminated untill that task is finished?

```
  @Bean
  public TaskExecutor myAsyncTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(30);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
    executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true); // How it behaves?
    //executor.afterPropertiesSet();
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MY-ASYNC-TASK");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
  }
```

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer? Yes

On shutdown ( either by hitting by a request to the shutdown end point or by calling applicationcontext.close ) by default, Spring's TaskExecutor simply interrupts all running tasks.

Note that your threads must be in an interruptible state (e.g. sleep) to actually be interrupted.

In some cases you may want to wait for all running tasks to be complete.

calling setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true) simply prevents interrupting the running tasks on shutdown and ensures that both the currently executing tasks and queued up tasks are completed.

( I assume this is because they are non-daemon threads that prevent application exit. )

In short, the answer to your question is yes.

You can play with the following piece of code. When you change setWait from false to true, you will see that the application will not exit until the sleep is over. When you set it to false, the application will terminate immediately.

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
    
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false);
        taskExecutor.initialize();
        return taskExecutor;
    }
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void runTaskOnStartup() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10_000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Sleep Interrupted!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext run = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        run.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell after extensive googling the root cause is that in Java 17 (possibly earlier) they deprecated Thread.stop(), making threads that cannot be interrupted or stopped via a flag... unstoppable from inside java.

I would love a better solution, but this clunky approach currently works for me:

- Use the ThreadExecutor to launch the thread.
- Add a "stop" flag that the thread code can check, ending the processing loop if set.
- To stop, set the flag.  Wait for a "stop tolerance time" for the thread to hit that flag check and end cleanly.
- After the tolerance time, if not stopped use an interrupt (2nd stop attempt).  I do it on the thread, which is possibly not ideal and it might be better to do it on the TaskExecutor.
- A second later, if the thread still has not stopped, I use the deprecated Thread.stop() as a final resort (3rd stop attempt).  This is known to be a **bad approach**, but has not caused **me** any problems for a decade.
- As another undesirable alternative to stop, there is always the option to kill the executable itself, by hand.  Nasty, but under some emergency circumstances it might be the only way to stop a long-running thread.

I sincerely hope I am wrong and that there is a better way to stop uninterruptible long-running threads, but I found no better answer anywhere.

If anybody knows of a better solution, please mention it and I'll edit this post.